# Proving an inequality on the sum of $\log$ of primes.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, summation

> Let $S(x)=\sum_{p\leq x} \ln(p)$ where $\sum_{p\leq x}$ denotes a summation over the positive prime numbers that are $\leq x$
>
> Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, S(2n+1)-S(n+1)\leq \ln\left(\binom{2n+1}{n}\right)$

I rewrote $S(2n+1)-S(n+1)$ as $\displaystyle \sum_{n+2\leq p\leq 2n+1}\ln(p)$ and assuming that $n$ is even, we may of course remove every even integer, yielding $$\sum_{n+2\leq p\leq 2n+1}\ln(p) \leq\sum_{k=n+2,k\;\text{odd}}^{2n+1}\ln(k) \leq \ln \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!(n+2)(n+4)\ldots(2n)}$$

Unfortunately, we don't have $(n+2)(n+4)\ldots(2n) \geq n!$

What should I do ?

Comment: All you have to do is show that the binomial coefficient is an integer and that it's divisible by every prime between $n+2$ and $2n+1$, inclusive.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, it works.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expanding out the factorials, the original inequality can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{n+1<p\leq 2n+1}\ln p + \sum_{k\leq n} \ln k + \leq \sum_{n+1<k\leq 2n+1} \ln k$$

If we let $P(n)$ and $C(n)$ be the set of primes numbers and composite numbers, respectively, in the range $(n+1,2n+1]$, then we can further reduce the inequality to:

$$\sum_{k\leq n} \ln k \leq \sum_{k\in C(n)} \ln k$$

Now, for each prime $p$ and integer $k$, let $a_p(k)$ be the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $k$, and let $P$ be the set of all primes. Expanding each $k$ into its prime factorization, the inequality becomes,

$$\sum_{p \in P} \ln(p){\sum_{k=1}^n a_p(k)} \leq \sum_{p\in P} \ln(p){\sum_{k\in C(n)} a_p(k)}$$

It suffices to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_p(k) \leq \sum_{k\in C(n)} a_p(k)$$

for all primes $p \leq n$. Or, since $a_p(k)=0$ for $p\leq n$ and $k\in P(n)$, it suffices to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_p(k) \leq \sum_{k\in C(n)} a_p(k) + \sum_{k\in P(n)} a_p(k) = \sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+1} a_p(k),$$
or that
$$ \sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+1} a_p(k) - \sum_{k=1}^n a_p(k) \geq 0$$
This is clear, since the given expression is simply the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $\binom{2n+1}{n}$.